# Detect if the SqlContext is read-only (e.g., SqlFunction)

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr, sql-function

In SQLCLR, I can detect if I'm inside an `SqlContext`, and if so, perform additional functions like writing to the pipe.

However, how do I detect if I'm inside a read-only SQL context, such as method with this attribute:

```
[SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read)]
public static void MyMethod()
{
}
```

The only way I can surmise is to walk back the stack and look for a method decorated with `SqlFunctionAttribute`?

Comment: Hi @Sören Kuklau, as such the context is not read-only - it is the function that is read-only; which BTW all functions are. E.g. in a function you can never perform actions which have side effects on the data. As a side note, why would you like to know this?

Comment: Because I have a logging function that can write to the database, and mustn’t try to do so while within an SqlFunction.